# Twilio Recording Video

Tags: twilio, videocall

I'm developing a system using VideoCall and Recordings. I want to show recordings in my web page, i got url recording like this
https://video.twilio.com/v1/Recordings/RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

But when i load it. it show a form to fill username/password

Can i get content of recordings for my web page without username/passwd (for example through API or something else)?

I have account_sid, auth_token, api_key information, ..etc

Please help me on this!
Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The URL you have there is to the [recording's resource in the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource). You can get a URL for the media itself by making a request to the [recording's media subresource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource#get-media-subresource). The media endpoint takes some arguments and returns a temporary redirect to the recording file. Check [the documentation on fetching a recording's media for more information](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource#get-media-subresource).

Note though, the recordings are not optimised for playing in a browser. The recording files are returned in the Matroska file format (`.mka` or `.mkv`). Chrome may play these, but other browsers likely won't. The best application for playing these recordings back is VLC Player.

If you are looking to generate player-friendly files check out the [Twilio Video Compositions API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource).